# To let Finder always open a folder with default window width and height

Tags: finder, macos, folders

The Finder seems to remember the width and height of window that last time I open that particular folder and set such. 
In other words, if I opened a folder and make the window really wide, the next time (after closing it) I open that folder, the window is still very wide. 
This remains true even if I restarted computer, and even if I delete the .DS_store inside the root of that folder.

How to let Finder forget all previously-remembered window size of every folder in this computer? 
I want that every time I open a new folder, Finder always apply the default size, the setting shipped with MacBook (This is about 1/2 width and 1/2 height of the whole window).

Though this is not big deal, it somewhat annoys me that when I have widened a window for some reason, the next time I open it, I have to manually adjust it back to smaller width and height for ease of reading, or the other way round.

Comment: I have googled, but everyone seems to ask Finder to open a window in _their custom defined_ width, not the default. By the way, some claim that deleting .DS_store in the folder's root makes finder forget window size, but it does not.

Comment: It may sound crazy (ok maybe I have compulsory personality...) but I have `find ~ -iname "*finder*.plist" | xargs rm` which deletes all preference files having 'finder' within its name. But everything remains the same. I wonder which `plist` does Apple saves the window size in!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is extreme, but works: (see also [Remove .DS_Store files from Mac OS X](https://helpx.adobe.com/dreamweaver/kb/remove-ds-store-files-mac.html))

```
sudo find ~ -name ".DS_Store" -depth -exec rm {} \;
```

Restart and observe that newly opened finder windows are of uniform size. This deletes all ".DS_Store"'s. It then seems that they store relevant data regarding window size.

I did this partly out of curiosity, or maybe I have compulsive personality. I don't recommend normal users to mess up with your computer like this, though.